# Get the total pages from print job

Tags: c#, printing, printqueuewatch

I was downlaod this code from [Monitor jobs in a printer queue (.NET)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51085/Monitor-jobs-in-a-printer-queue-NET)
And now I want to know the total pages from the print job.
I saw the Comments and add this code:

```
if ( data[ i ].Field == (ushort)PRINTERJOBNOTIFICATIONTYPES.JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_TOTAL_PAGES &&
    data[ i ].Type == (ushort)PRINTERNOTIFICATIONTYPES.PRINTER_NOTIFY_TYPE )
{
    uint pagesCount = data[ i ].NotifyData.adwData[ 0 ];
}
```

But I always get the wrong pages.
And I tried use "PrinterQueueWatch" and the total pages always 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [`Win32_PrintJob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394370(v=vs.85).aspx) class to get the print job, and you can get the total pages from that print job. Remember that the number of total pages is available after the print job status has moved from Spooling to Printing (in which I have experienced in my own code).

In my case, I use WMI to monitor print jobs, and on `EventArrived` event handler of the watcher, I add some line of codes to get the total pages of a print job.

Try this:

```cs
public void PrintJobChange(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    ManagementBaseObject objProps = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value;

    ...

    string jobStatus = (string)objProps["JobStatus"];
    uint totalPages = ((uint)objProps["TotalPages"]);

    Console.WriteLine("Status: " + jobStatus + ", Total Pages: " + totalPages);
}
```

Then `PrintJobChange` is subscribed to `EventArrived` handler:

```cs
public void MonitorPrintJobs()
{
    string queryClassName = "__InstanceOperationEvent";
    string queryCond = "TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PrintJob'";
    TimeSpan queryTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(1);

    try
    {
        WqlEventQuery eventQuery = new WqlEventQuery(queryClassName, queryTimeSpan, queryCond);
        ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(eventQuery);

        if (PrintJobChange != null)
        {
            watcher.EventArrived += PrintJobChange;
        }

        watcher.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string msg = string.Format("Error monitoring print jobs. Exception {0} Trace {1}.",
        ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        MessageBox.Show(msg, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

Console output of printing only 1 page to my dummy printer:

```
Status: Spooling, Total Pages: 0
Status: Printing, Total Pages: 1
```